# Dagger 2 component is not generated

Tags: android, kotlin, dagger-2

In my module, in my BaseApp class

```
class BaseApp : Application() {

    companion object {
        lateinit var appComponent: AppComponent
        val baseUrl = "https://api.github.com/"
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        appComponent = DaggerAppComponent.builder()
            .networkModule(NetworkModule(baseUrl))
            .apiModule(ApiModule())
            .appModule(AppModule(this))
            .localModule(LocalModule(this))
            .build()
    }
}
```

it can not find DaggerAppComponent.

What can be the cause for not generating Dagger Component . class ?

These are my module classes

This is ApiModule.

```
@Module
class ApiModule{

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApi(@Named("retrofit") retrofit: Retrofit) : API = retrofit.create(API::class.java)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApiClient(Api: API) = ApiClient(Api)

}
```

This is AppModule

```
@Module
class AppModule(val application: Application) {
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideApp() = application
}
```

This is LocalModule

```
@Module
class LocalModule(val application: Application) {

    private val authDatabase: AuthDatabase

    init {
        authDatabase = Room.databaseBuilder(application, AuthDatabase::class.java, "auth.db").build()
    }
    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideLocalStorage() = SharedPrefStorage(application)

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRoomDatabase(): AuthDatabase = authDatabase

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideAuthDao(authDatabase: AuthDatabase): AuthDao = authDatabase.getAuthDao()
}
```

This is NetworkModule

```
@Module
class NetworkModule(val mBaseUrl: String) {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideHttpLoggingInterceptor(): HttpLoggingInterceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor().apply { level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideSecretHeaderInterceptor(local: LocalStorage, authDatabase: AuthDatabase): SecretHeaderInterceptor = SecretHeaderInterceptor(local, authDatabase)

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideOkHttpClient(loggingInterceptor: HttpLoggingInterceptor, secretHeaderInterceptor: SecretHeaderInterceptor): OkHttpClient {
        return OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .addInterceptor(loggingInterceptor)
            .addInterceptor(secretHeaderInterceptor)
            .build()
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideGson(): Gson {
        return GsonBuilder().create()
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("retrofit")
    fun provideRetrofit(gson : Gson, okHttpClient: OkHttpClient): Retrofit {
        return Retrofit.Builder()
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .baseUrl(mBaseUrl)
            .client(okHttpClient)
            .build()
    }

}
```

And this is my Component class

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = [(AppModule::class),(NetworkModule::class),(ApiModule::class),(LocalModule::class)])
interface AppComponent{

    fun inject(extensionStudyActivity: ApplyExtensionStudyActivity)

    fun inject(applyStayingActivity: ApplyStayingActivity)

    fun inject(changePasswordActivity: ChangePasswordActivity)

    fun inject(noticeActivity: NoticeActivity)

    fun inject(pointLogActivity: PointLogActivity)

    fun inject(registerActivity: RegisterActivity)

    fun inject(signInActivity: SignInActivity)

    fun inject(splashActivity: SplashActivity)

    fun inject(applyMusicDialogFragment: ApplyMusicDialogFragment)

    fun inject(bugReportDialogFragment: BugReportDialogFragment)

    fun inject(institutionDialogFragment: InstitutionDialogFragment)

    fun inject(logoutDialogFragment: LogoutDialogFragment)

    fun inject(applyGoingFragment: ApplyGoingFragment)

    fun inject(applyGoingDocFragment: ApplyGoingDocFragment)

    fun inject(applyGoingEditFragment: ApplyGoingEditFragment)

    fun inject(applyGoingLogFragment: ApplyGoingLogFragment)

    fun inject(applyMusicFragment: ApplyMusicFragment)

    fun inject(applyMusicLogFragment: ApplyMusicLogFragment)

    fun inject(mealFragment: MealFragment)

    fun inject(myPageFragment: MyPageFragment)

    fun inject(noticeDescriptionFragment: NoticeDescriptionFragment)

    fun inject(putInFragment: PutInFragment)
}
```

What am i supposed to do?
solve it Please...

Answer (score 1):

Remove all your dagger2 implementation code and replace with it below.

```
def final dagger_version = '2.22.1'
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger:${dagger_version}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android:${dagger_version}"
implementation "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:${dagger_version}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:${dagger_version}"
kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:${dagger_version}"
```

and apply `apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'` in gradle.

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```

Comment: I did. Since I use Kotlin, I added it to gradle as example


```gradle
// dagger2
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-android-processor:2.22.1"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:2.22.1"

    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger:2.22.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android:2.22.1'
    implementation 'com.google.dagger:dagger-android-support:2.22.1'
```

Comment: Do you have other solutions?

Comment: Please sync, clean , and rebuilt your project.